# How long can melted chocolate last?

Tags: freezing, storage-lifetime, chocolate

I would like to know how long melted chocolate can last in a freezer? My wedding is in 4.5 months and would like to start now to melt chocolate for the party favours

Comment: Why would you put it in the freezer in the first place? Chocolate will last for more than 4.5 months at room temperature.

Comment: I agree with @rumtscho, no need to fill up your freezer, just store your shaped chocolate at room temperature.

Comment: Furthermore, fine chocolate doesn't like to be frozen. Ideally, chocolate should never see extreme temperatures except for gentle melting.

Answer (score 4):

Freezing chocolate is not ideal, because when it defrosts it can 'bloom' - you may have seen this happen with chocolate that has been stored unwrapped in the fridge. It gets an unsightly white coating.

If you absolutely must freeze it, wrap it very well, and bring the temperature down slowly. First let it cool out of the fridge, then in the fridge for several hours, *then* in the freezer.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Nicole and welcome to Seasoned Advice! Per the information found  [here](http://www.eatbydate.com/other/sweets/chocolate-shelf-life-expiration-date/) , 4.5 months should not be a problem.

It should be noted that freezing chocolate is not generally recommended. However, if you must do so you should be very detailed in your effort and you need to be sure and plan for enough time to do so properly.

As @ElendilTheTall notes, the chocolate must be cooled very gradually. It must be wrapped tightly and then placed in an air tight container. (I would recommend vacuum sealing.)

Also, when defrosting, the temperature must be brought up very slowly in order to prevent condensation from forming. When removing from the freezer wrap it in a towel and place in the fridge for several hours. Remove the towel and put back in the fridge for several more hours. When removing from the fridge, re-wrap it in the towel so that it comes up to room temperature very slowly.